# Use PreferenceActivity to configure widget, how retrieve preference?

Tags: android, widget

i'm using PreferenceActivity class to configure my widget. 
PreferenceActivity class automatically saves user preferences, so in 
widget update service i can call context.getSharedPreferences() and i 
obtain user preferences. 
Problem is follow: if you have many widget of same type, how 
PreferenceActivity class saves prefs? how i can load appWidgetId 
specific prefs from sharedPreferences?

Answer (score 7):

For AppWidgets and preferences I really liked this tutorial

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part1
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part2
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/mastering-android-widget-development-part3

They give a tutorial where a preference is saved for jointly with the appwidget ID and it is shown how it is retrieved for updating the individual widgets.

Comment: that is an activity's Prefference, not the Widget one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but I'll take a stab at it.  You use the id of your resource specified in the xml to call findPreference(CharSequence key).

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been asked a long time ago, here are a few thoughts.
I am planning to do the same thing myself.

Premier's question brings two points:

1) the configuration activity is a PreferenceActivity, which means that the user input can't be recovered by using findViewById() on a layout. mportuesisf's answer explain how to use a key attribute.

2) the widget instance must save its own preferences. A way to do it is by using the widget ID in a prefix. See http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.html